# How can I get back data of user on Parse?

Tags: database, swift, object, parse-platform

I want to get back data in "requestActive" in "User" on Parse.t

I try this :

```
var user = PFUser()
var requestActive = user["requestActive"]
```

but : error "instance member 'user' cannot be used on type 'viewController'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `user` at the top level of your view controller.

But then, still at the root level, you try to use it with `user["requestActive"]`: you can't do that.

You have to use `user` *in a method*, for example `viewDidLoad`.

So let's say the type of `user["requestActive"]` would be a String (just for the example), you would do something like:

```
var user = PFUser()
var requestActive: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestActive = user["requestActive"]
}
```

Of course, you have to replace String with your actual type.