# send variable id to api to get user

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, swifty-json

I have this API for get user by id

```
http://api.programize.me/2/projects/lawyer/api/v0/lawyer/show/{id}/{token}
```

when I try send my user id shows me this error

```
Instance member cannot be used on type "my viewController name"
```

I write API like this:

```
http://api.programize.me/2/projects/lawyer/api/v0/lawyer/show/\(lawyerId)/{token}
```

`lawyerId` it is var of my user id from another viewController
, What is the correct way to send id to my API ?

Comment: Read the error message carefully. The issue is not related to the API.

Comment: @EricD i know is not related the API but i don't know how i can send id to this Api ? cause when i write just any number in API its working but doesn't working with var !!

Comment: I just told you that your issue is not related to the API and your response is... talking about the API again. Stop. Take a breath. Step back a few meters and look at the issue again: `Instance member cannot be used on type "my viewController name"` What is this message telling you? Do you see now that it's *not* about your API? :) It's related to *the var* and where you're using it. Search Google with the error message, you will understand.

Comment: @ِEricD I read this, but I did not understand what I have to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055147/error-using-swift-instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcontroller

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36621471/2227743

Comment: @EricD Thank you very much it works!!

Comment: Closed as duplicate: although the questions are different, they address the same problem and an answer in the linked page solved OP's issue.